# Is there a relation between self-interaction errors and integer-discontinuities in Kohn-Sham-DFT?

Tags: density-functional-theory, kohn-sham, self-interaction

I am wondering whether or not ***self-interaction error*** and ***integer-discontinuity*** in Kohn-Sham density functionals, are related to each other?

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no.

The exact functional should have a piecewise linear behavior in the number of electrons [Phys. Rev. Lett. 49, 1691 (1982)](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.49.1691), but this is not true for common density functional approximations, and self-interaction errors *do* affect behavior at fractional electron numbers.

Now, if you apply the Perdew-Zunger self-interaction correction, then not only do you mitigate the one-electron self-interaction error (N.B. the correction is often problematic, see [Adv. At., Mol., Opt. Phys. 64, 1 (2015)](https://doi.org/10.1016/bs.aamop.2015.06.004) and [J. Chem. Theory Comput. 12, 3195 (2016)](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jctc.6b00347)) but also introduce step-wise behavior in the functional due to the added term; orbital energies in PZ-SIC are often better than in Kohn-Sham DFT. There's also been a lot of work on the so-called Koopmans' compliant functionals by Marzari et al.